# Display the Text color Based on json color code 0xAF001D

Tags: javascript, css

I need to fetch the color code from below json file :

```
{ 
"text" : "VALENTINES DAY ",
"color" : "0xAF001D" 
}
```

So I tried below code :

```
$('.container').append(
            '<div class="txtContainer" ' +
            'style="' +                                   
            'color: ' + layer.color + '; ' +                
            '">' +
            layer.text +
            '</div>');
    }
```

**Issue** :

if i use color names as **"color" : "red" or "color" : "#AF001D"**, then it will work fine.... but  for **0x** color codes **"color" : "0xAF001D"** , its not fetching properly, instead its displaying in white color.....

Instead of displaying like below image,

[image]

It displaying like below image :

[image]

If anyone want , Below is full code :

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/bZOGeK

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " fb post\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "fb post",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "fb post",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 788,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "height" : 788,
          "src" : "",
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 940,
          "type" : "image",
          "name" : "bg_image"
        },
        {
          "x" : 290,
          "height" : 788,
          "src" : "",
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 650,
          "type" : "image",
          "name" : "shape_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 450,
          "height" : 140,
          "src" : "",
          "y" : 304,
          "width" : 430,
          "type" : "image",
          "name" : "shape_2"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "MyriadPro-Regular",
          "x" : 555,
          "y" : 579,
          "src" : "70d83a42df6cebb355f5be7ccc0bc4c4_MyriadPro-Regular.otf",
          "width" : 220,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xAF001D",
          "size" : 12,
          "text" : "Reservation recommended +00 123 456 789 ",
          "height" : 9,
          "name" : "edit_reservation"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "MyriadPro-Regular",
          "x" : 522,
          "y" : 513,
          "src" : "70d83a42df6cebb355f5be7ccc0bc4c4_MyriadPro-Regular.otf",
          "width" : 283,
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xAF001D",
          "size" : 9,
          "text" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.",
          "height" : 45,
          "name" : "edit_body"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "Montserrat-Bold",
          "x" : 598,
          "uppercase" : true,
          "y" : 486,
          "width" : 134,
          "src" : "2ccd95bae3f2a0c8249205ca5dfbed24_Montserrat-Bold.ttf",
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xAF001D",
          "size" : 15,
          "text" : "35$ per person",
          "height" : 13,
          "name" : "edit_price"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "MyriadPro-Regular",
          "x" : 507,
          "uppercase" : true,
          "y" : 464,
          "width" : 316,
          "src" : "70d83a42df6cebb355f5be7ccc0bc4c4_MyriadPro-Regular.otf",
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xAF001D",
          "size" : 19,
          "text" : "4 COURSE DINNER & FIRST DRINK FOR 2",
          "height" : 13,
          "name" : "edit_info"
        },
        {
          "justification" : "center",
          "font" : "ArchivoNarrow-Bold",
          "x" : 559,
          "uppercase" : true,
          "y" : 257,
          "width" : 211,
          "src" : "611aa93612da8fde1b17d87368355d1f_Font83.otf",
          "type" : "text",
          "color" : "0xAF001D",
          "size" : 30,
          "text" : "VALENTINES DAY ",
          "height" : 22,
          "name" : "edit_sale"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 940,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "fb_post_5"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // upload image onclick

    $('.container').click(function(e) {
  // filtering out non-canvas clicks
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

  // getting absolute points relative to container
  const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
  const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

  const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
  // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
  $canvasList.parent().css({zIndex: 0});

  $canvasList.filter(function () { // filtering only applicable canvases
    const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect()
    return (
      absX >= bbox.left && absX <= bbox.left + bbox.width &&
      absY >= bbox.top && absY <= bbox.top + bbox.height)
  }).each(function () { // checking white in a click position
    const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
    const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if (pixel[3] === 255) {
      $(this).parent().css({zIndex: 2})
      target = this.id;
      console.log(target);
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#fileup').click();
      }, 20);
    }
  })
});
 
 
    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

     function json(data)

        {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

            let layer1 = data.layers;
            width = layer1[0].width;
            height = layer1[0].height;
            let counter = 0;
            let table = [];

            for (let {
                    src,
                    x,
                    y
                } of arr) {
                $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

                var mask = $(".container").mask({
                  imageUrl: imageUrl,
                    maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });

                    },
                    id: counter
                });
                table.push(mask);
                fileup.onchange = function() {

                    let mask2 = table[target];
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                    document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
                };
                counter++;
    // get the text
    
            }
drawText(data);
        }

json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready


// extempl code - get the text

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

$('.container').append(
            '<div class="txtContainer" ' +
            'style="' +
   'text-align: ' + layer.justification + '; ' +
   'font-family: ' + layer.font + '; ' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
   'width:' + layer.width + 'px; ' +                       
   'color: ' + layer.color + '; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
             'height:' + layer.height + 'px;' +
            '">' +
            layer.text +
            '</div>');
    }

}
// extempl code end 



// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        updateStyle();
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        function updateStyle() 
  {      
                //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            image = new Image();
            image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                div.css({
                    "width": image.width,
                    "height": image.height
                });
                img = new Image();
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            };
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
             console.log("load");
            //if (img)
               // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        function loadMaskImage(imageUrl) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.container img {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:250px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
   z-index:999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer{ position:absolute;  text-align:center; color:#FFF}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Price question: Is `0xAF001D` a valid color format in CSS? ( ) Yes ( ) No

Comment: You could convert `0x` to `#`

Comment: @04FS Thanks for comment, i dont know its valid color format or not, but client gave json file in that format, so i need to get the color.....

Comment: Please tell me reason for downvote, so that i will correct it....

Comment: @varunagarwal Thanks for comment,  i cant convert manually as i have thousands of json files with same format 0x.....

Comment: Who said anything about converting anything in/about the JSON files? You have the specific value in a variable, `layer.color` - so replace it at _that_ point.

Comment: @vickeycolors AF001D should be valid color, you can use replace function of your favourite IDE to replace '0x' to '#'

Comment: @04FS sorry, i didt knew that..... can you please guide me how to do that ?

Comment: @chaugiang there are thousands of json files with same format 0x..... i need some dynamic solution.....

Comment: `'color: ' + layer.color.replace(/^0x/, '#')` will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to demonstrate what the above comments are talking about.

```
var fixedColor = layer.color.replace('0x','#');

$('.container').append(
        '<div class="txtContainer" ' +
        'style="' +
        'text-align: ' + layer.justification + '; ' +
        'font-family: ' + layer.font + '; ' +
        'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
        'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
        'width:' + layer.width + 'px; ' +                       
        'color: ' + fixedColor + '; ' +
        'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
         'height:' + layer.height + 'px;' +
        '">' +
        layer.text +
        '</div>');
```

Comment: The code `layer.color.replace('0x','#');` replace `0x` of any position of string, use `^` for good practice, which means on start of the string i.e  `layer.color.replace(/^0x/, '#')`

Comment: No worries! just remember to also take the advice of @Sachink also!